# Why does patch.contains_point() behave differently from patch.get_path().contains_point() when checking if points are within a polygon?

Tags: python, matplotlib, path, patch

With matplotlib.patches, the `patch.contains_point(xy)` method seems to work differently from `patch.get_path().contains_point(xy)`, at least after having added the patch to the axes. See difference `True/True` and `True/False` below. I can't find any documentation on this difference. Does anybody know? I also have difficulty seeing how `contains_point()` decides if the point is inside the path given the path's vertices are the unit rectangle in this case and not the rectangle I specified.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rect = patches.Rectangle([0.2, 0.3], 0.8, 0.5)

pnt = [0.4, 0.45] # point inside rect
print("Before adding patch to axes:")
print(rect.get_path().vertices)
print(rect.contains_point(pnt))
print(rect.get_path().contains_point(pnt))

print("After adding patch to axes")
ax.add_patch(rect)
print(rect.get_path().vertices)
print(rect.contains_point(pnt))
print(rect.get_path().contains_point(pnt))

plt.show()

Before adding patch to axes:
[[0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 0.]]
True
True
After adding patch to axes
[[0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 0.]]
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, I just faced the same issue and solved it.

The issue is after adding patch to the axes, you need to give the coordinates/points in display reference frame. This can be performed with:

```
ax.transData.transform()
```

I added one line to your code ignoring import statements. So the code goes here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rect = patches.Rectangle([0.2, 0.3], 0.8, 0.5)

pnt = [0.4, 0.45] # point inside rect
print("Before adding patch to axes:")
print(rect.get_path().vertices)
print(rect.contains_point(pnt))
print(rect.get_path().contains_point(pnt))

print("After adding patch to axes")
ax.add_patch(rect)
print(rect.get_path().vertices)
# added lines
pnt_in_display_coordiantes = ax.transData.transform(pnt)
print(rect.contains_point(pnt_in_display_coordiantes))
print(rect.get_path().contains_point(pnt))

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Before adding patch to axes:
[[0. 0.]
[1. 0.]
[1. 1.]
[0. 1.]
[0. 0.]]
True
True
After adding patch to axes
[[0. 0.]
[1. 0.]
[1. 1.]
[0. 1.]
[0. 0.]]
True
True
```

For more: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html